# Why does my GET route work on local machine but not Heroku

Tags: heroku

I have a database credential that I worked with on development. Starting the server gets me the response message as expected. A GET request route fetches data from a MySQL database that I configured. All these work perfectly on local env. When I deployed to Heroku, I used the same db config credentials exactly how I used them on dev env. But here, I get the default response message on home route, but when I route to get data from the database I get this {"message":"connect ETIMEDOUT"}. What could be wrong?

Comment: Where is your database hosted?

Comment: It's hosted on AWS.

Comment: And have you set up appropriate rules for incoming connections?